# How can I mathematically approach to correct Positive radial distortion using python?

Tags: python

A Numpy generated mxn data matrix has pincushion effect( Positive radial distortion I hope).
How can I mathematically approach it to overcome this issue?
[Plot with pincushion Distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7kSo.png)

I would appreciate if you could share some literature.
Thanks in advance.

Is it possible to overcome this using OpenCV? if possible help me to do that?